# How i get a continuation of a value with Extractor (JMETER)?

Tags: apache, jmeter, element

I am trying to take the Information from an element from the middle on.
And this value is only displayed this way

see image:

It would be the value "info_se"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression extractor under your sampler that return the full html. Save in reference name as info and then use it later ${info}

```
  info_s=(\S+)"

  Template $1$

  Match No. 1
```

Comment: I use: "CSS/JQuery Extractor" or  "Extractor XPath"?

Comment: regular expression extractor as post processor

Comment: "info_se=(\S+)" It doesn't work or i'm not knowing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `?` sign (as well as other [meta characters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)) in your regular expression with a back slash so the whole expression would be something like:

```
a href="#" data-url="Cervello/Release.aspx\?info_s=(.+?)"
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regex Escape]

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 0):

My error was another, this "info_s" field was decoded, so the system needs this coded encoding.
I managed to find several that stored this value, and in the parameters of HTTP request, I was informed to code the extracted value of the Extractor

Answer (score 0):

I get, finding in the html the field that stored this value "info_s", decoded, then using the encoder option of jmeter, I was able to capture the correct value.